# Conversion of dat file into jpg

Tags: visual-c++

I have a set of `.dat` files. They are images of characters from the UNIPEN character database. I want to convert them into `.jpg` images for further processing. I use the following simple code  for that, but it gives an error message saying that `.dat` extention is invalid. Can someone suggest a method for that?

```
Bitmap ^myImage = gcnew Bitmap("D:\\charimage\\a.dat");
myImage->Save("D:\\test.jpg");
```

Comment: I would imagine, given [UNIPEN](http://unipen.nici.kun.nl/)'s mission, that the images are stored in some sort of [lossless or vector format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_file_formats) (JPEG is neither of those). You will need to determine what file format you are working with and then do the conversion. Changing the extension is likely insufficient.

Comment: Changing a file's extension does not magically convert it to a different file format, any more than putting a label on a Ford that reads "Ferrari" makes the Ford worth 50x more.